# how to make back button work from the second frame to the first frame

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jframe

i have an assignment and i got stack at making this back button. i could go to second frame from first frame but cannot make it from the second frame to first frame.

The First frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel label;
    JButton Add,Delete,Update,Display,Exit;
    public Test() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("JDBC");
        label = new JLabel("Database");
        Add = new JButton("Add Data");
        Delete = new JButton("Delete Data");
        Update = new JButton("Update Data");
        Display = new JButton("Display Data");
        Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        //setBounds
        Add.addActionListener(this);
        Delete.addActionListener(this);
        Update.addActionListener(this);
        Display.addActionListener(this);
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        //button added
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Add Data")){
            this.setVisible(false); //the first frame is still open
            new add().setVisible(true); //this one is work
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Delete")){}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Update")){}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Display")){}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) { //Launch the Application
        new Test();
    }
}
```

The Second Frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class add extends JFrame{
    JButton button, button2;
    JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5;
    JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4, l5;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    public add() {
            JFrame frm = new JFrame();
            frm.setVisible(true);
            frm.setSize(500, 500);
            frm.setLayout(null);
            frm.setTitle("JDBC");
            button = new JButton("Insert");
            button = new JButton("Back");
            l1 = new JLabel("ID : ");
            l2 = new JLabel("Name : ");
            l3 = new JLabel("Adress : ");
            l4 = new JLabel("Gender : ");
            l5 = new JLabel("IP : ");       
            tf1 = new JTextField();
            tf2 = new JTextField();
            tf3 = new JTextField();
            tf4 = new JTextField();
            tf5 = new JTextField();
            //setBounds
            //frm added
    }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Insert")){
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/academic", "root", "abc"); 
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql;
                    sql = "INSERT INTO student VALUES(" +
                          "'" + tf1.getText() + "'," + 
                          "'" + tf2.getText() + "'," +
                          "'" + tf3.getText() + "'," +
                          "'" + tf4.getText() + "'," +
                          tf5.getText() + ")";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                }catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }catch(Exception es){
                    es.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Back")){
                this.setVisible(false);
                Test().setVisible(true);//Test() cannot finded on cmd 
            }
        }
}
```

any idea guys ? plz help me

Comment: Why not use [card layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?

Comment: i dont know, is it have another way ? like mine ?

Comment: It allows you to have one container with swappable content, which is what I think you're trying to accomplish with two containers. Simplifies the solution a bit, plus you get the added benefit of using a layout manager instead of having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: can u give me example ? or directly use in my code ? plz :)

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of that page I linked you above.

Comment: @KiraKatou Why are you using multiple frames? You can have multiple panels and display them accordingly using CardLayout.

Comment: @user343760 i dont like card layout display. thats why i use multiple frame

Comment: @KiraKatou you example is not working at all, it is not only about second frame and back button. You should learn Java basics first

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One is by making both frames singletons and manipulate with their instances.

First frame:

```
public class First {

    public static First mInstance;
    private JFrame frame;


    public static First getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null) 
            mInstance = new First();
        return mInstance;
    }

    private First() {
        frame = new JFrame("First");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton back = new JButton("SWITCH");
        frame.add(back);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                frame.setVisible(false);
                Second.getInstance().getFrameInstance().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JFrame getFrameInstance() {
        return frame;
    }

}
```

Second frame:

```
public class Second {

    public static Second mInstance;
    private JFrame frame;


    public static Second getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null) 
            mInstance = new Second();
        return mInstance;
    }

    private Second() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton back = new JButton("SWITCH");
        frame.add(back);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(First.getInstance().getFrameInstance());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                frame.setVisible(false);
                First.getInstance().getFrameInstance().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public JFrame getFrameInstance() {
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, that's not how you make singltons in Java, second off, that greatly reduces the re-use of the class, a better (more general solution), might be to use a form of MVC, where the controller is "pushing"/"popping" views on/off a stack and making determinations (through the model) about what can/can't be done

Answer (score 0):

Add this sample code inside second `JFrame`'s back button click event listener

```
new Main().setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

In `newMain()` is object of the first `JFrame`.